# Reusing of MediaMetadataRetriever - is it possible?

Tags: android

I am wondering if it is possible to reuse single `MediaMetadataRetriever` object for the purpose of getting metadata from multiple files?

If yes - should I call `release()` method after each file or just set different datasource and call `release()` after all files being processed?

API refererence is not precise about that :/

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse the object. You code would look something like this:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    mmr.setDataSource(files[i]); 
    mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
    mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); // frame at 2 seconds
    byte [] artwork = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
}

mmr.release(); // all done, release the object
```

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out yesterday, but you've reassured me ;)